# My computer is not listed on the Ubuntu certified desktops list - I wish to add mine. How?

Tags: hp, hardware

I have a very old (maybe 2014?) HP all in one desktop computer.  It is the kind that the computer is built into the back of the screen (no, I would never buy this thing - it was given to me).  This line of old computers from HP is called TouchSmart 520.  I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 working on it.  WiFi works, ethernet works, built in web cam works, so far everything seems to work just fine.

I went to the Ubuntu certified desktops list to add my computer but I did not find a button
to add.  Did I miss something?  Do I need to go someplace else to add this old desktop computer?

Any links would be helpful.

Many thanks,
mraroid

Comment: I think this is a system for vendors to get hardware certified, and I don't think you can do anything else with it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not actually about Ubuntu, but about a hardware partnership program.

Comment: I used the list to see if my old computer would even work with ubuntu.  I think it was a list made by folks that has success.  My mistake..

Comment: There is [a corresponding list at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006). Get a user ID there and add a post about your computer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Certified hardware happens when Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEMs) agree to make their equipment available to a team of Canonical engineers in Taiwan.

Those Canonical engineers do the hardware testing and help create the OEM kernels sometimes needed for newer hardware that's not in the mainline kernel yet. That's also where some of the new hardware starts its journey to the mainline kernel, and that assistance getting their hardware into the kernel is one of the big inducements for OEMs to participate.

Users, not being OEMs, cannot ship their laptops to this team to get their personal hardware included on the Certified Hardware list.

There is currently no open, community-maintained hardware database. Folks are welcome to organize themselves and create one.

You are also welcome to blog about your successful hardware compatibility, or discuss your great hardware in various social media venues as well as Ubuntuforums.org. Search engines will find it.